# Why is my search function not being passed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to pass a search filter function into my search bar components. But i keep getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
the search function is not recognized my context file is here 
https://github.com/CodingOni/Ecommerce-Store/blob/master/src/context.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ProductContext from '../../src/context';

const ProductFilter = () => {

  const productConsumer = useContext(ProductContext);
  const text = useRef('');
  const { search, searchResults } = productConsumer;

  useEffect(() => {

      console.log(` product context ${productConsumer}`)
  });

  const onChange = e => {
    if (text.current.value !== '') {
      search(e.target.value);
    } else {

    }
  };
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        ref={text}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search Keywords..."
        onChange={onChange}
        id=""
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default ProductFilter;
```

Comment: On what line is the error triggered?

Comment: its triggered on my search function in my onchange function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> useContext accepts a context object (the value returned from
>   React.createContext) and returns the current context value for that
>   context.

You pass react component to useContext which is default export from '../../src/context'.

In context file you need export PoductContext

```
export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer, ProductContext };
```

..

```
import {ProductContext} from '../../src/context';
```

Comment: Thank you how would i redirect to a certain react router url on submit?